# Persist Mediawiki skin by URL parameter

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to allow users of my Mediawiki wiki to maintain their own choice of skin by preference, while ensuring that if the `useskin` parameter is added to the URL, subsequent requests made to the page in that window will persist (i.e., the URLs on the page will also include the `useskin` parameter or the like)--but without interfering with the cache of pages where the parameter was not used (i.e., users who visited a page without `useskin` will not see URLs cached with `useskin` or vice versa).

There is an extension to persist the `useskin` parameter, [PersistUseskin](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PersistUseskin), but it doesn't seem to create separate caches.

(My purpose is to allow iframe navigation of my site to use a bare skin (so more of the page can be seen in a small space) without interfering with the user's skin preferences when they visit my site otherwise.)

Note that I am not interested in page-specific or namespace-specific skinning (as discussed at [In MediaWiki is there a way to force a group of pages to have a particular skin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853749/in-mediawiki-is-there-a-way-to-force-a-group-of-pages-to-have-a-particular-skin) ). I simply want a URL parameter to perpetuate skinning info for that window (only) regardless of page.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the easiest thing to do here would actually be to write some Javascript which detects the presence of the useskin parameter, and then ensures that every link displayed in the UI has ?useskin= appended to the URL. This is probably the most lightweight/easiest way to ensure all links in the UI have the useskin parameter. This should also trivially help keep this behavior limited to the iframe. You could create a [lightweight extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aDeveloping_extensions) to serve up the JS, or you could even use [Mediawiki:Common.js](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Common.js) to hold the JS.

You mentioned you wanted to do this 'without interfering with the cache of pages where the parameter was not used'. What kind of caching are you talking about? If you're using a basic reverse proxy cache, like squid or varnish, they will naturally cache pages with different URLs independently. So, http://foo.com/index.php and http://foo.com/index.php?useskin=awesome will be cached differently.

Comment: Thank you. That is a reasonable idea though maybe I ought to handle it using PHP DOM before output (as through OutputPageBeforeHTML?) so that the links will have the skin attached to links before document ready and without the imperfect solution of adding an onclick handler which doesn't change what shows as a tooltip near the status bar on link hover.

Comment: As far as caching, I think I should be just using the default caching with Mediawiki--nothing else, but it did not cache it differently as I would have expected when using the `GetLocalURL` hook (when I visited a page with `useskin`, it cached that version so it showed for version without `useskin`).